# Deleting specific elements (objects) inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've tried to delete multiple entries in an array.

These entries are objects and I need to locate the object meeting specific criteria.

```
    var pending = [];
    a.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        if(entry.b == data) {
            pending.push(index);
        }
    });
    pending.forEach(function(entry) {
        a.splice(entry, 1);
    });
```

The problem is that it only deletes half of what I want (when `b = data`) and even deletes some random entries...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's in `a`, what is `data`? What are you trying to keep, show us some relevant (albeit simplified) code, with variables filled in?

Comment: Its possible that you're getting false positives from your non-strict equality comparison. Have you stepped through this in the debugger?

Comment: With each `splice()`, the indexes in `a` shift for everything `> entry`, so the next `entry` is off by 1, next by 2, etc. Look into [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: AHH~! that's right @JonathanLonowski! I've overlooked that fact! So .filter()??

Comment: @cloud1250000 Yeah. David already posted an example of `.filter()`. It isn't a *mutator* like `.splice()`, so it won't alter `a`. It instead creates a new `Array` without the filtered element that you can assign back into `a` as `a = a.filter(...);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `a` is an array of objects, that you want to filter in order to keep only those whose `b` property is equal to the string `'data'`. That being the case:

```js
// this outputs to the console, you should probably press 'F12'
var a = [{
    'b': 'data'
  }, {
    'b': 'something else'
  }, {
    'b': 'data'
  }, {
    'b': 50
  }],
  pending = a.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.b === 'data';
  });

console.log(pending);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: So basically, I should redo an array where I keep the message I want?

Comment: Perfect! it's working great! I did that
    pending = a.filter(function(elem) {
 return elem.b != data;
     });
   a = pending;